# Top values from a table

Tags: mysql

I have this SQL query to get how many times certain category's books has been rented.

```
SELECT Category.name, COUNT(*) AS "times rented"
FROM Category
INNER JOIN Book ON Book.category=Category.name
INNER JOIN Rent ON Rent.book_id=Book.id
GROUP BY Category.name
ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC
LIMIT 1
```

Now this would work perfectly if I wanted to get THE most popular book. The problem lies in "LIMIT 1". I have multiple books that have been rented just as many times as the result of query above. Removing "LIMIT 1" just returns all of the rented categories.

Let's say the above query returns this

```
name | times rented
Adventure 153
Comics 153
Biography 102
Romance 80
```

How do I return both "Adventure" and "Comics"?

Answer (score 1):

You can use MAX().

```
SELECT Category.name, COUNT(*) times_rented
FROM Category
INNER JOIN Book ON Book.category=Category.name
INNER JOIN Rent ON Rent.book_id=Book.id
INNER JOIN (select  MAX(COUNT(*)) max_count FROM Category GROUP BY Category.name) t ON t.id = Category.id AND Category.times_rented = t.max_count
GROUP BY Category.name
```

Answer (score 1):

you can use max of count to compare, and replace `"` with `backticks` in `times rented` to use it as alias without warnings.

```
SELECT Category.name, COUNT(*) AS `times rented`
FROM Category
INNER JOIN Book ON Book.category=Category.name
INNER JOIN Rent ON Rent.book_id=Book.id
GROUP BY Category.name
having  `times rented` = (select MAX(cnt) from 
(select COUNT(*) as cnt FROM Category GROUP BY Category.name) temp
)
```

Comment: This comes up with error    #1111 - Invalid use of group function

Comment: So the error is gone but the result is the opposite I'm trying to achieve here. Instead of the most popular categories it returns the least popular.